# Should I use SqlBulkCopy or Stored Procedure to import data

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, bulk-load

I've got a log file which is 248 MB and it can extend up to a GB. So you can imagine how many rows there can be.I need to import all the rows into a table in an SQL Server database. For that I first create a DataTable and add all the lines in the log file into that DataTable as new rows. This happens pretty fast. More than a million records get added to the table in about 30 seconds. After the table is filled with the lines I then import the records in the DataTable to the database using stored procedure. However this phase executes very heavily. Now I wonder, if I should use SqlBulkCopy WriteToServer method instead or should I keep with this way? If SqlBulkCopy is a better choise then should I use DataTable or IDataReader version. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with SqlBulkCopy for data imports of any real volume like this. The performance difference vs. SqlDataAdapter can be large. e.g. I [blogged](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html) as performance comparison for importing 100K rows:

SqlBulkCopy:    1.5885s
SqlDataAdapter: 25.0729s

You can get even greater throughput if you use a TableLock option with SqlBulkCopy, which in my test took the import then down to 0.8229s.

It's also worth noting that with SqlBulkCopy, you can have multiple instances bulk loading a segment of data into the same destination table in parallel without them contending with each other. Apologies for another [external link](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/sqlbulkcopy-to-sql-server-in-parallel.html), but I think it's relevant. That's about loading into a heap table, no indexes, for optimal performance, which may not be an option for your current scenario but is definitely worth knowing of.

Comment: As you've practices a lot with SqlBulkCopy you might know why I get "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completetion..." error. I increased the connection timeout to 600 seconds. But I get the error  in less than half a minute.

Comment: Try setting the BulkCopyTimeout on SqlBulkCopy (in seconds) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.bulkcopytimeout.aspx

Comment: Thank you @AdaTheDev very much. You saved me tons of time

Comment: @AdaTheDev So your answer and blog post compare SqlBulkCopy and a series of insert statements via SqlDataAdapter, but what about a stored procedure?  I can send off a data table as a custom type and do a SELECT FROM INTO  (or INSERT INTO FROM, I always get those two backwards).  At that point I’m doing the insert as a single SQL set operation. Is SqlBulkCopy still better here, and if so why?

Comment: @AriRoth Hey, so you have extra options with SqlBulkCopy to further speed up the bulk insert (i.e. split the data into chunks and import in parallel). I had a followup blob post linked to that original that goes over that. "Better" is subjective, as it depends on scenario - i.e. for a smaller number of rows, I'd probably go with a TVP. For larger, I'd go with SqlBulkCopy and batch them up into the DB. HTH.

Comment: @AdaTheDev I'm moving away from a row by agonizing row insert (CSV upload) and want to move to an efficient solution like TVP or SQLBulkCopy. I'm leaning toward TVP since Stored Procedures are used throughout my project (easier to transition) but when you mention 'smaller number of rows go with TVP' what is that 'smaller number'? So far I have 200k rows but could potentially grow to 500k max. I also plan on using stored procedures anyway to provide users with feedback on why their data is failing (due to data typo's)

Comment: @AVu - I actually wrote an updated blog post last year on this with a comparison of various volumes of rows, and multi-threaded vs. single threaded: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/sqlbulkcopy-vs-table-valued-parameters-bulk-loading-data-into-sql-server